# List of values to ndimension list

Tags: python, list

could someone give me some ideas of what I can do with this code?
The user will give a number of values as an argument, and the shape will be the dimensions of the list.

The problem here I is with the v variable, I want to use the v variable to index the values(list) so I can change the nth dimension of the list, so for example.

In the example under where i do v+m, I want the index to not start for 0 where i get the value 1 from the value list, but to get the value 5, but I cant find a solution to do this since i need to define v at the start with 0 and check if its not 0.

Any help is appreciated. ps. I dont want to use any numpy arrays or anything other than lists

```
def test(shape , *values):
    n = shape[1]
    m = shape[0]

    nDim = [[0 for column in range(m)] for row in range(n)]

    values = list(values)

    for x in range (n):
        print(x)
    
    
        v = 0
        if(v%m == 0):
            v +=m
    
        for y in range (m): 
            nDim[x][y] = values[v]
            v += 1

    return nDim

m = test((4,2) , 1, 2 ,3, 4 , 5 ,6 , 7 , 8)
```

Comment: Could you reformulate the question. is difficult to follow what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close!

It's true you need to set `v=0` but you should do that only once, before the first loop, so you won't reset it between loops. And then your modulo condition is not needed at all, as you increment `v` in every iteration so choose every `*values` element once.

```
    v = 0
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(m):
            nDim[x][y] = values[v]
            v += 1
```

You could even omit `v` as it can be calculated from `x`and `y`

```
nDim[x][y] = values[x * m + y]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```py
def to_list_of_lists(shape, *values):
    values = list(values)
    result = []
    for row in range(shape[1]):
        start_index = row * shape[0]
        stop_index = start_index + shape[0]
        result.append(values[start_index:stop_index])
    return result

x = to_list_of_lists((4,2) , 1, 2 ,3, 4 , 5 ,6 , 7 , 8)
```